# Auto orientation

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

In my project I am required to implement the orientation feature of iPhone. For this I have created two xib files and one `UIViewController` controller file, one for landscape and other for portrait. I have taken one `UIViewController` because the content of the xib files are same.

Now I want to load the respective xib file depending on the rotation and the content should remain populated in the `TextField` when the specific file loads. How should I implement this?

**CODE:**

```
if( orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
{
   NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"landscapeView" owner:self options:nil]; UIView *viewItem = (UIView *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0]; self.view = viewItem;
}
else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) 
{
   //same above lines only different nib name 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in your `init` method of `UIViewController` device orientation using following code

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])
{
     // load view for landscape mode
}else
{
     // load view for portrait mode
}
```

And choose .xib file that correspond to current orientation.

Hope, this will work.

Comment: Thank you for helping.Depending on orientation i have loaded the nib file using the following code NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UIViewName"
                                      owner:self
                                    options:nil];
        UIView *lview = (UIView *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
        lview.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.jpg"]];
        self.view = lview;The thing is i am not able to retain the text values which were entered by the user on change in uiview.Can you suggest me overriding method

Comment: if( orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {    NSArray *nibArray =    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"landscapeView" owner:self options:nil];
        UIView *viewItem = (UIView *)[nibArray objectAtIndex:0];
        self.view = viewItem;
                
          }
    else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
       same above lines only different nib name
    }

Comment: I don't see there any problems. If you want to ask question about another thing than it is better to close this one if it is solved and open new one where you will describe another new problem.

Comment: Using loadNibNamed i am able to load the respective view. But it resets all entered texts and data. The ViewController for both this xibs is same but why it is not retaining the textfield values.

Comment: You should do this programmatically or use one .xib file and change locations of subviews in code. I suggest last one.

Comment: If you have any idea of how this can be achieved programmatically, can you just give an insight of it

Answer (score 0):

it is a very bad approach please set xib by code and use

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

above one for rotation and below one to set the xib.

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

I hope this helps you.